# When an object is moving at a constant velocity,would the normal force and $mg$ be equal?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Does the object's normal force and $mg$ cancel out, resulting in the two force becoming equal, or would one force be greater than the other? Thank you!
Edit: Also would the $mg$ be considered weight or would it be more correct to just refer to the force as $mg$?

Comment: As for your question #2, it is unusual to refer to it as "mg", since that is a mathematical expression for magnitude of the force, not the name of the force. It's more conventional to call it "weight" or "the force of gravity".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the object is moving on a horizontal frictionless surface, then the normal force equals $mg$.

Yes, $mg$ is the weight of the object.

Comment: @AubreeSmith if this answered your question, consider marking the answer as "accepted" by clicking the little gray check mark.

Comment: To be clear: the OP specifically mentions that the object is moving at constant velocity, so the surface need not be frictionless.  If you like his answer, accept it!